# flowchart tikz nodes and shapes

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, node-connections, flow-charts, tikz-shape

I am trying to replicate the following flowchart [image]

with the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

  \tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum   height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
   \tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right  angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
   \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,    text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
   \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
   \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]


   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

    \node (start) [startstop] {Planning};
   \node (in1) [startstop, below of=start] {Input};
   \node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {Process 1};
   \node (pro2) [process, below of=pro1] {Decision 1};
   \node (dec1) [decision, below of=pro2, yshift=-0.5cm] {Decision 1};
   \node (dec2) [decision, below of=dec1, yshift=-1cm] {Decision 2};

  \draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
  \draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
  \draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2);
   \draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (dec1);
   \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (dec2);

  \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

However I am unable to setup the nodes to write in several lines, to draw a diamond make the proper connectors with the text "yes" or "no".

Should I use any other setup and configuration?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: instead of `minimum width` define `text width`, or use manual way to breake text in more lines. for this you shol add to nedes options `align=...` (center, left, right, justfy). read chapter *17 Nodes and Edges* of **tikz & pgf manual** v 3.0.3a, page 214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly simple to add the connections to your code, no need to switch gears. **UPDATE**: Added the text widths and some sample texts, `{\Huge BIG THANKS $\to$ @Zarko}`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning}

  \tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, text width=3cm, minimum   height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
   \tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right 
   angle=110, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
   \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,    text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
   \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
   \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]


   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.8cm,font=\sf]

    \node (start) [startstop] {\textbf{Planning}: To identify and define the
    needs for production.};
   \node (in1) [startstop, below=of start] {\textbf{Input}: Task
   distribution\dots};
   \node (pro1) [process, below=of in1] {Process 1};
   \node (pro2) [process, below=of pro1] {Decision 1};
   \node (dec1) [decision, below=of pro2] {Are we achieving the targets?};
   \node (dec2) [decision, below=of dec1] {Decision 2};

  \draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
  \draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
  \draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2);
   \draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (dec1);
   \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (dec2);
   %new
   \draw [arrow,-] (dec1.west) -- ++(-1,0) node[midway,above]{yes} |- (pro2.west);
   \draw [arrow,-] (dec2.west) -- ++(-2,0) node[midway,above]{yes} |- (pro1.west);
   \draw [arrow] (dec2.east) -- ++(2,0) node[midway,above]{no} coordinate (right)|- (start.east);
   \draw [arrow] (right|-in1) -- (in1.east);
   \draw [arrow,dashed] (pro2.east) -- ++(1,0) coordinate(almostright) |- (start.-10);
   \draw [arrow,dashed] (almostright|-in1.-10) -- (in1.-10);

  \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you forgot to show how to write multi line text in nodes :-). i mentioned this in my comment ;-).

Comment: @Zarko OOOPS. Yes, you're right, thanks a lot!!